# como descomponer con oaxaca-blinder en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Ya tengo el mejor modelo, pero necesito descomponer los salarios en genero. Los salarios están en función de edad, educación y experiencia, pero, no sé cómo agregar la variable dummy que es p6020 que es genero esta variable esta definidad como "hombre" "mujer"
esto es lo que tengo:

```
 result<-oaxaca(formula=INGLABOH~ESC+tenure+tenure2+EDAD+EDAD2 | P6020|, data=D, R=1000)
```

pero me sale

```
 Error: unexpected ',' in "R<-oaxaca(formula=INGLABOH~ESC+tenure+tenure2+EDAD+EDAD2 | P6020|,"
```

no sé, cómo continuar.
Alguien que me pueda guiar en lo que tenga equivocado

Comment: Me da la impresión que el último pipe de la formula, el que está despues de `P6020` está de más: `... | P6020|,`